# Meaning and usage of きっと良{よ}い

Tags: meaning, usage

What is exact meaning of きっと良い? The ～良い part is easy to understand, it means "good". But きっと～ part is not very clear to me. Also, could this phrase be used in official language?

Comment: More questions that ask about きっと: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/21103/usage-of-%E3%81%95%E3%81%9E-and-%E3%81%8D%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A8 and http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/11825/whats-the-difference-between-%E3%81%9C%E3%81%B2-and-%E3%81%8D%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A8-when-inviting-someone-to-do-something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what the Wisdom Japanese-English Dictionary says:

> きっと
>   〖確かに〗surely, certainly; 【きっと…する】be sure [certain] to 〘do〙; 〖間違いなく〗without fail（必ず⇨①）〖…に違いない〗must 〘do〙 (!do は通例状態を表す動詞) ; 〖十中八九〗probably（⇨多分）.

In official language usually more elaborate phrases are used, but I am not completely sure about the usage of this one in any more or less official papers.